# Hiding icons in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to hide icons in the QGIS print composer?

I have used the Customization page in QGIS to create an ini file to simplify the QGIS interface for my users, but I can't see how to do the same for Print Composer.

I know I can turn off entire toolbars, but I need to keep a few icons to allow printing, zooming and changing text.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the below script in Python console

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

toolBar = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QtGui.QToolBar,'mMapNavToolBar' )
       
toolBar.removeAction(self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QtGui.QAction, 'mActionZoomFullExtent'))
```

you can get the names of the action and toolbar from Customization page